# Not working return in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

this is my code:

```
$("#MainContent_btnSave").click(function () {
            if (($("#MainContent_txtFunc").val() == "") || ($("#MainContent_cmbLoc").val() == "")) {
                alert("Please fill options.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $("#msgbox-loading").show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Ajax.aspx",
                    data: { func: "getexist", catfunc: $("#MainContent_txtFunc").val(), catdes: $("#MainContent_txtDesc").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var parsed = $(data);
                        var exist = parsed.filter("[id=exist]").text();
                        if (exist == "NO") {
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (exist == "Yes") {
                            alert("already defined.");
                            $("#msgbox-loading").hide();
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        $("#msgbox-loading").hide();
                        HidePopup('popup');
                        alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
                    }
                });
            };
        });
```

My code is check mandatory and If empty mandatory, an error message display and or if not empty mandatory, first display the loading and then Ajax run.
After running Ajax i want if page send "NO" run button postback and if page send "Yes" stop button postback. 
but Unfortunately, after run ajax and page send "Yes" run button post back.

please help.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. You cannot return values like this.

Comment: i can send data by ajax and refresh the page?

Comment: Yes, you can. But in your case you could use $.Deferred object. More information here http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jgesfjzz/1/ demonstrates how you can use $.Deferred to solve your problem.

Comment: Does the postback occur immediately after the ajax method is exited? Are you able to reach the code if(exist =='YES')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use .[ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)() for commands that you want to fire after ajax completed